# wp_nav_menu not appearing for a couple pages

Tags: categories, theme-development, navigation

*I solved the problem with the page, the correct answer is ptriek's comment below.*

Well I'm having a bit of an odd problem here, wp_nav_menu works on all pages EXCEPT my category pages (probably my archive page too but there's no links on the website to the archive pages so that's alright).

Although there is archive.php in my theme files, this controls what is displayed on category, tag, archive, author, etc. pages.

I just don't understand why, since every page uses the same header.php to display wp_nav_menu, it won't show up for the category pages.

Am I overlooking something? I've been banging my head against my keyboard trying to figure this out and it just won't work!

Using a very simple code: `<?php wp_nav_menu('container_class=menu-header&theme_location=primary'); ?>`

Comment: you could have look on http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-nav-menu-dissapears-in-category-pages-1 - see solution at the bottom (haven't tested it though)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, but with a newer version of Wordpress (3.7.1).

On pages with custom taxonomies of custom posts, the wp_nav_menu was not shown. The solution below worked for me.

in functions.php of the theme:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts' );
function my_pre_get_posts($query) {
  if ($query->get('post_type') === 'nav_menu_item') {
    $query->set('tax_query','');
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me with Wordpress 4.0 as well.

Comment: Thanks! Spent hours looking for solution, this worked like a charm...

Answer (score 2):

Implode's answer is right and helped me a lot. I tried to implement a hook (`pre_get_posts`) for avoiding to display posts of subcategories. My hook worked well despite of no more Nav-Menus.

So, when change the `tax_query` you have to avoid doing this for the query with `post_type == 'nav_menu_item'`.

Answer (score 2):

Answer by Implode solve issue only if you are not using other queries like 'meta_key' even . I found complete solution [here](http://casabona.org/2015/03/fix-wp_nav_menu-custom-type-archives-wordpress/).

```
function fix_nav_menu( $query ) {
    if ( $query->get( 'post_type' ) === 'nav_menu_item' ) {
        $query->set( 'tax_query', '' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', '' );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'fix_nav_menu' );
```

Comment: The question was solved. Please don't add extra answer!

Comment: @Dan, I had the same issue, but with little bit different situation. This answer wasn't solved my issue but link I found solved it. So maybe somebody else will find this answer helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me. The answer found in this link on the second last post/comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-nav-menu-dissapears-in-category-pages-1/?replies=15#post-1859168

Just need to add this on the theme's function.php file

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
  if(is_category() || is_tag()) {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if($post_type)
        $post_type = $post_type;
    else
        $post_type = array('nav_menu_item','post','articles');
    $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
    return $query;
    }
}
```