# wp_nav_menu() not working on Custom Search Page

Tags: menus, search

I'm using **[WP Custom Search](http://www.webhammer.co.uk/bespoke-wordpress-plugins/wp-custom-search)** plugin to generate Advanced Search in one of my newly developed WP site. Though the plugin is not completely bug-free, but it's working just fine (excepts some Undefined Offset warnings, I'm ignoring them for its better support in searching).

But recently noticed that the `wp_nav_menu()` on the `header.php` is not working when I'm on the search page. It's a simple code as it's used in many of my WP sites:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header_menu', 'menu_class' => 'site-header-menu' ) ); ?>
```

That's working on all other pages, BUT the `search.php` - a typical search template.

I've tried the most-cited solution from:

- [this WP Support thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-nav-menu-dissapears-in-category-pages-1) — failed,
- [this SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10886623/1743124) — failed, and
- [this WPSE thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35264/wp-nav-menu-not-appearing-for-a-couple-pages) — failed

Typically the search page contains a `?s=` on the URL, but using this plugin, I'm getting:

```
http://example.com/?search-class=DB_CustomSearch_Widget-db_customsearch_widget&widget_number=preset-1&[search_queries_and_conditions]=&search=Search
```

Is that a cause I'm failing echoing the menu? ([Live site here](http://sultanstationery.com/), and the Advanced Search is on the left)

Comment: I tried http://sultanstationery.com/?s=test and the menu is being shown. So as you have already figured the plugin probably cause that. Have you tried the wp_get_nav_menu_items function to see what you get when you are on a search page?

Comment: It appears to be an issue with the plugin, [see this support thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/nav-menu-not-showing-on-custom-search-result-1).

Comment: @Laxmana just tried `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` - it's returning the menu array in all the pages, except the Search page.

Comment: I see. Sorry but I can't think a way to help you more. If you find the solution (as far as I searched there are other people having the same problem) please post it. It would be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Milo stated, it seems it's a problem of the plugin. And solely for this project of mine, I'm not going for such a big dig out, and I'm actually going for a fallback. **I repeat, it's not a solution, just a problem hiding measure.**

I checked, as Laxmana said that, is there any menu items found there. If there're menu items, show the menu items as a nav_menu, if not, show the default menu (in my case, I'm just showing the "Home" button there - as my site demands that urgently).

```
        <?php
        $menu_name = 'header_menu';
        $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
        $menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id );
        ?>
        <?php if( !empty($menuitems) ) { ?>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header_menu', 'menu_class' => 'site-header-menu' ) ); ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="menu-top-menu-container">
            <ul class="site-header-menu" id="menu-top-menu">
                <li class="no-margin">
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread but the problem still exists. I think this is a bug. Default queries such as nav should not be affected in making custom search page. Anyways, this is how I fixed it:

```
function fix_nav_menu_in_search($query)
{
    if (is_search()) {
        $query->set('post_type', ['your_cpt', 'nav_menu_item']);
    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'fix_nav_menu_in_search');
```