# pre_get_posts fix to show menu on CPT Archives broken WP 6.0

Tags: menus, pre-get-posts

Before WP 6.0 we have had to add this pre_get_posts fix to show the wp_nav_menu on custom post type archive and taxonomy pages: [wp_nav_menu not appearing for a couple pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35264/wp-nav-menu-not-appearing-for-a-couple-pages?newreg=bcd29300b6894866996cb8970c554b0f)

Here is an example of the menu not showing on the CPT taxonomy page: https://www.sbcv.org/video-category/resource-video/

There is a bug in 6.0 that when this is in the functions.php file the WP menu adds every menu item and other wp nav menus to each wp nav on both the backend in the menu editor and the frontend of the site. Makes for a very large menu anywhere a wp menu is called.

Example of the broken menu: https://acbase.wpengine.com/

Comment: Are you sure there's a menu assigned to the theme-location? WordPress will output all pages by default if there's no nav menu assigned to a location.

Comment: @admcfajn Yes There is one set. This is happening on a lot of site's and seems to be a WP 6.0 bug. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/56154

Comment: Have you tried removing the pre_get_posts filter that was added before? 
Are you using an array or string when calling wp_nav_menu? I noticed that in the [example linked here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35264/wp-nav-menu-not-appearing-for-a-couple-pages) uses `wp_nav_menu('container_class=menu-header&theme_location=primary');` whereas I would expect: `wp_nav_menu([ container_class=>'menu-header',theme_location=>'primary' ]);`. Also, is there a reason the pre_get_posts code is not wrapped in `if (!is_admin()){...` to prevent it from happening on the backend?

Comment: @admcfajn I'm using an array: wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); The only reason i'm didn't wrap it in the if was because I didn't think of it and none of the code examples online had it.

Comment: So it seems that the fix is just to remove the $query->set( 'tax_query', '' ); line.

Comment: In the [example provided](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35264/wp-nav-menu-not-appearing-for-a-couple-pages?newreg=bcd29300b6894866996cb8970c554b0f) that's the only code that actually does anything. It might be worth it to remove the entire function.

Comment: @admcfajn Actually the part that I need and still works is the meta_key line. I am sorting my posts by meta_key. If I remove the function completely the menu still disappears on my tax page that's sorted by meta_key.